# All possible causes of "Found no TGT's in LSA"

Tags: authentication, ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos

I’m using Kerberos to connect to my RDMS. If I don’t use SSO, authentication is successful. However, if I use SSO, I receive:

```
>>> Found no TGT's in LSA
Principal is null
null credentials from Ticket Cache
            [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed
Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication
```

Possible reason for this error that I am aware of:

1. Allowtgtsessionkey needs to be set to 1 (it is)
2. Windows version is too old (I am using Windows 7 so this is not the issue)
3. User is in local administration group (it is not)

I feel like I have exhausted all possible reasons I could get this error. Are there any others that I am missing?

Comment: Can we get more details on the overall architecture?  What OS, and what type of RDMS is the application server running?  Are the the Windows 7 client and the application server participating in an Active Directory domain?  What software is being used to access the RDMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure you are using a keytab file and it has the correct principle inside of it.
2. Download the latest/appropriate JCE jars and place them into the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib//security directory on the application server.  The files are:

> ```
> US_export_policy.jar
> local_policy.jar
> ```

3. If applicable, check your XML config in your WEB-INF on your application server and make sure it doesn't contain errors.